# How do I make it so when I create a user it gets added to a 'user' Firestore?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Currently having difficulty figuring out how to add the ability that, when an account is created, the account is added to the Firestore under a collection called 'users'. From what I have seen from other people they added in something like this

```
.then then(userCredential => {
firestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user.uid).set({name})
}
```

This is my code as it stands after my attempt at it. I am unsure where I should be adding in my code. Currently I have it under `this.fireauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)` and the attempt I did is there the program works fine with how it is, I can register an account and see the account in the authentication on the firebase authentication users tab but no 'user' collection is created in the Firestore. I am currently stumped where I should go from here. All I really need is the User-Id/name to be stored in the Firestore.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LoadingController, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage {
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  error: string = '';
  username: string = '';
  image: number;
  constructor(private fireauth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private toastController: ToastController, private platform: Platform, public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public alertController: AlertController, private firestore: AngularFirestore) {

  }

  async openLoader() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please Wait ...',
      duration: 2000
    });
    await loading.present();
  }
  async closeLoading() {
    return await this.loadingController.dismiss();
  }

  signup() {
    this.fireauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.user) {
          console.log(res.user);
          this.updateProfile();
          userCredential => this.firestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user.uid).set({
              name
            })
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(`login failed ${err}`);
        this.error = err.message;
      });
  }

  updateProfile() {
    this.fireauth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        user.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.username,
          photoURL: `https://picsum.photos/id/${this.image}/200/200`
        })
          .then(() => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
          })
      }
    })
  }

  async presentToast(message, show_button, position, duration) {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      showCloseButton: show_button,
      position: position,
      duration: duration
    });
    toast.present();
  }
}
```

This is the current rules that I have set for my database.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {


    match /users/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with the arrow function:

```js
userCredential => this.firestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user.uid).set({name})
```

It seems you only initialize function but never call it. Try change this line to just:

```js
this.firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({name})
```

or call the anonymous function if you prefer your solution for example:

```js
//... some logic
const initialize = user => this.firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({name})

initialize(user)
```